# How to redirect a user to the content of a different URL while still showing the original URL to the user?

Tags: redirects, url

I use a domain (`www.example.com`), which I would like to redirect to an different web space (`www.example1.com/user567`).

What I use so far is an index file with a redirect header:

```
<?php
// Permanent redirection
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.example1.com/user567");
exit();
?>
```

I would like to keep the root URL, when a user access the site. Currently the browser (and search results) are just redirected to `www.example1.com/user567`.

I can not access the *.htaccess* file. Is there another technique I can use?

Comment: Is there an issue with moving whatever is on example1.com to example.com so you don't have the two domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two techniques that you can use:

### Frame redirects

This is a technique where the first domain serves an HTML frameset that hides the other URL.  It has some disadvantages:

- Users may not be able to navigate out of the frameset.   Clicking links may not change the URL, even if they navigate to external websites.   Users may have a hard time bookmarking or sharing your content.
- [Search engines see right through it](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72119/when-using-a-framed-redirect-which-site-does-google-attribute-content-to-for-se).   They won't refer users to the frameset, but rather to the deep URL.

### Reverse Proxy

Your server is configured to fetch the documents from the other domain and reserve them at the preferred URL.  This has different disadvantages:

- Search engines see duplicate content.
- It may make pages somewhat slower to load.